# Docker compose, interpolation of the assigned port

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given the following docker-compose.yml. I would like to scale the service kafka, but not assign any specific ports. The environment variables configuration should be able to interpolate the contextual assigned port by docker-compose. Is that possible?

`zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  ports:
    - "9092" #I am not assigning a remote port here, leaving that to docker-compose
  links:
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    KAFKA_PORT: 9092
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, PLAINTEXT://localhost:${ASSIGNED_PORT}" # I would like ASSIGNED_PORT here to be the assigned port of docker-compose
    KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 2):

If your environment variables are in the context where you running the `docker-compose up`, your configuration options can contain environment variables.

Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which docker-compose is run.
For example, suppose the shell contains `ASSIGNED_PORT=8000` and you supply this configuration:

```
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  ports:
    - "${ASSIGNED_PORT}:9092"
```

When you run docker-compose up with this configuration, Compose looks for the `ASSIGNED_PORT` environment variable in the shell and substitutes its value in. In this example, Compose resolves the port mapping to `"8000:9092"` before creating the `kafka` container.

If an environment variable is not set, Compose substitutes with an empty string. In the example above, if `ASSIGNED_PORT` is not set, the value for the port mapping is `:9092` (which is of course an invalid port mapping, and will result in an error when attempting to create the container).

Both `$VARIABLE` and `${VARIABLE}` syntax are supported. Extended shell-style features, such as `${VARIABLE-default}` and `${VARIABLE/foo/bar}`, are not supported.

Check this on [Docker documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)

Answer (score 1):

Compose does not inject any environment variables so that is not currently possible.

However, since you're already exposing the docker socket to the container, you could use an entrypoint script to query for the exposed port and set the environment variable before starting kafka.